# React pattern for making the props of some element depend on the DOM rendered by another element

Tags: reactjs

my React component has an element that renders a markdown asset. At the bottom of the page, I have a facebook share button, to which I'd like to pass the markdown content as a quote. The only way to get hold of the content, is to access the DOM.
In pseudocode:

```
return
  <>
    <MarkdowComponent file='some-asset.markdown'/>
    <ShareComponent 
      url={window.location.href} 
      quote={document.querySelector(<<selector targeting elements in rendered markdown>>).textContent}
    />
  </>
```

I've tested this, and it seems to work, but I wonder if this is an appropriate solution. Can I safely assume that all preceding elements have been rendered in the DOM before a later element is reached? What if the `<ShareComponent>` comes before the `<MarkdownComponent>`?

Is there a React pattern for making the props of some element depend on the DOM rendered by another element?

Best regards,
Vic

Comment: `Is there a React pattern for making the props of some element depend on the DOM rendered by another element?` no. 
`Can I safely assume that all preceding elements have been rendered in the DOM before a later element is reached?` You can *not* safely assume that you'll get what you are looking for. Plus `document.querySelector(...).textContent` will run on every render, which is too expensive imo. Is this your own `MarkdownComponent` or a third party library? And can you link to it? Basically does it provide you any useful api?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm using react-markdown. It has an extensive API, but not in the sense that it would help me, as far as I can judge. I did wrap it in a separate component though, so perhaps I could provide it with a function as a prop, that it could call in a hook after being rendered for the first time, to send the quote to the parent component? The parent component should have it as state, so it will re-render to fill in the <ShareComponet>. I've read about useCallback and use Memo patterns, they may be useful here?